# Faster alternative to the Windows.Security.Cryptography classes on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, cryptography

I am writing a program for Windows 8 that encrypts a lot of data (over 100MB at a time) and have noticed that even when using multi-threading, the encryption APIs on Windows 8 are slower than the Cryptographic Service Providers (CSPs) on previous versions of Windows. I was wondering if there was a faster way to encrypt files using AES on Windows 8.

Comment: Is there a third party library available for Windows 8 that is suitable for your system?  Most new OSes take some time to bed in while developers get to know their details.

Comment: @rossum -- There's plenty of .NET encryption libraries out there, but those would most likely even be slower than the native implementation that comes with Windows 8! (managed code tends to be significantly slower at tasks like cryptography than highly optimized native code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft CryptoAPI Next Generation (CNG) is a successor of old CSPs,it's fully native. First implemented in Windows Vista, it is still available in W8.

Why not to use them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the SecureBlackbox library, it is commercial (with free trial), but implements all the stuff on it's own.
And, anyway, any managed code will be somehow slower than native one.